Bulk API v2 not returning `isPkChunkingSupported` attribute in API result
I'm playing around with the Bulk 2.0 APIs - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/bulk_common_diff_two_versions.htm
In the API call to get the information about the job - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/query_get_one_job.htm, the documentation mentions that it'll return the attribute isPkChunkingSupported with a boolean value of true/false.
However, I do not see the attribute being returned at all. The details of the query are as follows:
CreateJob body:
{
  "operation" : "query",
  "query" : "SELECT Name FROM Account",
  "contentType" : "CSV",
  "columnDelimiter" : "COMMA",
  "lineEnding" : "LF"
}

Response from get API
{
    "id": "<some query ID>",
    "operation": "query",
    "object": "Account",
    "createdById": "<some Id>",
    "createdDate": "2024-06-05T19:22:22.000+0000",
    "systemModstamp": "2024-06-05T19:22:44.000+0000",
    "state": "JobComplete",
    "concurrencyMode": "Parallel",
    "contentType": "CSV",
    "apiVersion": 50.0,
    "jobType": "V2Query",
    "lineEnding": "LF",
    "columnDelimiter": "COMMA",
    "numberRecordsProcessed": <number of records>,
    "retries": 0,
    "totalProcessingTime": 5227
}

As per this doc - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/async_api_headers_enable_pk_chunking.htm, chunking is supported for the Account entity.
Is there a reason why that particular attribute isn't being returned in the API result?
